# I am trying to install Oracle 10g but it comes up with an exception of missing file

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sqlplus

I am trying to install oracle10g but it comes up with an exception of missing file `isqlplus.ini`.

[image: exception is in picture]

Answer (score 1):

iSQLPlus is web-based version of SQLPlus, so I presume that nothing *terrible* will happen if you ignore this error (presuming that this will be the only error you get during installation). SQLPlus will still work.

Where did you acquire installation files from? The only *legal* source is Oracle Technology Network's [Download](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html) section (I'm not talking about Oracle partners nor edelivery); maybe your version is corrupt?

Furthermore, how come you're installing 10g? This is a 4 major versions old database (the newest is 18c, then 12c, 11g, 10g). 10g isn't available any more, and is out of support for 5 years now (unless I'm wrong about it). OK, you may have a valid reason to install it (would you mind to share it with us)? If not, I'd suggest you to install a newer database version.

Comment: 18c is actually a point release of 12cR2. Oracle have just moved to number their versions by the year of release.

Comment: Thank you, @APC. I've never even seen 18c (and was just *counting* version numbers). Vast majority of (production) databases I have access to is still 11g, along with some 10gs (should be *retired* in a year or so).